# 14.04.3 Live USB not booting only on desktop

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, gparted

Acer Aspire XC-610 desktop computer

Sandisk Cruiser USB 3.0 16GB

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Dell Inspiron 15 Laptop

I downloaded ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-i386.iso and created a live USB using Startup Disk.  Live boots normally on the Dell laptop, but it doesn't boot at all on my Aspire desktop.

I have checked the BIOS settings, turned on and off the secure boot and rearranged boot devices but when I boot and press F-12, I only get 3 "ubuntu" options, none of which are the Live USB.

When running Gparted, I got the following error: 
[QUOTE]/dev/sdd contains GPT signatures, indicating that it has a GPT table.  However, it does not have a valid fake msdos partition table, as it should.  Perhaps it was corrupted -- possibly by a program that doesn't understand GPT partition tables.  Or perhaps you deleted the GPT table, and are now using an msdos partition table.  Is this a GPT partition table?[\QUOTE]
I was getting an image of an empty USB drive in gparted, so I tried creating a format. I had to create a partition table first, and it wiped out the drive.

I deleted everything and ran startup disk again. Now I get the image below.

[image: gparted print screen]

Ubuntu Live boots on my laptop, but it still doesn't show up in my desktop regardless of my secure boot settings in the BIOS for the uefi.

I also have the same image burned on a 4GB Sandisk Cruiser USB 2.0 device and the desktop boots and runs Ubuntu fine from it.

I have tried changing USB outlets in the computer.  I tried the USB 3 port, and two of the USB 2 ports with both devices and I get the same results, the 2.0 device works, but the 3.0 device doesn't boot.

Either one boots on the laptop, but the 3.0 is just a little faster than the 2.0.

Comment: The 32bit image doesn't work with UEFI (Unless you have Legacy support enabled). Also, try plugging the 3.0 stick into a 2.0 port and see if it works.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that.  I didn't realize it was the 32 bit version. Funny, it does work with the laptop though. LOL

I'll download the 64 bit and try it.

As for the 2.0 port, it's a no go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 32bit image doesn't work with UEFI (Unless you have Legacy support enabled). Also, try plugging the 3.0 stick into a 2.0 port and see if it works. – the_Seppi Dec 8 '15 at 12:08